# Upgrading to Xcode 4.2 produces a lot of SudzC warnings

Tags: xcode, warnings, xcode4.2, suppress-warnings, sudzc

I'm working on an iOS App and I'm using [SudzC](http://sudzc.com/) to interface with a web service.

It works great, but under Xcode 4.0 it would give me three warnings. Two of them I was able to fix and the third I didn't figure out but I figured I'd come back to it later before my project was done.

A few weeks back I upgraded to Lion and Xcode 4.2. Now there's a whole lot more warnings on the exact same code. I've gone in and resolved some but others I'm not yet skilled enough to know how to fix. Also we modified the web service so this is code I've recently re-generated, so I don't think it's the fault of the SudzC site (I've been generating it through the website)

Has anyone else had this experience with SudzC and Xcode 4.2? Do you just ignore the warnings? Suppress them? Fix them? Is there something I'm doing right/wrong?

Comment: I have converted WDSL to code by Sudzc and tried to build after adding it to project. It showed ARC warnings and errors. I tried setting flag to remove ARC errors but still could not build. I am using Xcode 4.6.3. Its mentioned in issues in their site about the error got after upgrading Xcode from version 3. Please help!